# How do I join tables from two MySQL databases located on different servers?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

We have a website hosted by a major international company and our package includes a number of MySQL databases: these are on different servers. I wish to run an SQL query to select items using a LFET JOIN between tables on two different databases.

In the PHP script I set up two separate database connections then ran the SELECT query referring simply to the fields in the two tables (there were no common field or table names between the databases). This failed to run. Following hints found in various searches on the internet I proceeded to:
1. extend the references to the format databasename.tablename.fieldname
2. ensure that the two database connections were completely different & add the "true" parameter

```
$db=MYSQL_CONNECT($server, $user, $password, true) or die ( "<H3>Server unreachable</H3>");
$seldb=MYSQL_SELECT_DB($database) or die ( "<H3>Database non existent</H3>");

$dbM=MYSQL_CONNECT($serverm, $userm, $passwordm, true) or die ( "<H3>members database server unreachable</H3>");
$seldbM=MYSQL_SELECT_DB($databasem) or die ( "<H3>Members database non existent</H3>");
```

The MySQL query still failed.

I then produced a script structured as follows

- connect to database1
- query datbase1
- connect to databaseM
- query databaseM

This worked.

I next structured the script

- connect to database1
- connect to databaseM
- query database1
- query databaseM

The query of database1 failed.

Having the structure

- connect to databaseM
- connect to database1
- query database1
- query databaseM

resulted in the first query running but the second failing.

Can anyone help, or is it not possible to do something like:

connect to two databases and then have a php command like

```
 $SQL="SELECT db1 roles.HMRSmembershipNumber, people.called,  people.lastname
       FROM roles LEFT JOIN people ON roles.HMRSmembershipNumber = people.HMRSmembershipNumber
  WHERE role LIKE 'EC Member%'
 ;";
```

Comment: This will be helpful: http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/

Answer (score 4):

sounds like what you are looking for is called [federated storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html):

> The FEDERATED storage engine is available beginning with MySQL 5.0.3.
>   It is a storage engine that accesses data in tables of remote
>   databases rather than in local tables.
>
> The FEDERATED storage engine is available beginning with MySQL 5.0.3.
>   This storage engine enables data to be accessed from a remote MySQL
>   database on a local server without using replication or cluster
>   technology. When using a FEDERATED table, queries on the local server
>   are automatically executed on the remote (federated) tables. No data
>   is stored on the local tables.

Comment: From my experience the federated storage engine is not as awesome as expected. The worst thing for me was that it would add ~0.5 sec overhead to each query (to handle out the connection, i assume). And that was in a fairly small 1GBit LAN with both servers in the same network segment.

Comment: perhaps, but it's an option the OP should explore and make a feasibility decision for himself

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but this does not appear to be available from our web hosting company (and looks like quite a learning challenge for a non-expert too!).  Regards,  Andrew

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do although im not sure it's very efficient is to populate an array with data from one DB, and an array populated with data from another Db, and use array functions to process them, possibly array_merge, etc.. Just a thought!

Comment: Array handling is something I struggle with! I have achieved one task by creating an array from a table in one database and looking things up in it while processing the output from another database. Very inelegant but it worked! Your suggestion is much appreciated. Regards, Andrew.

Answer (score -1):

> I wish to run an SQL query to select items using a LFET JOIN between tables on two different databases.

That's impossible.

Comment: what about joining against a federated table?

Comment: go make his hoster company install this engine.

Comment: I do answer practical questions.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I feared.